# A diffeomorphism between one-sheet hyperboloid and $\mathbb{R}^2 -\{0\}$

Tags: differential-geometry

As shown in the following image, in the book "Analysis and Algebra on Differentiable Manifolds" on page 54, it is proven that there is a diffeomorphism between one-sheet hyperboloid and $\mathbb{R}^2 -\{0\}$:

[image]

I would like to understand that how can obtain The equations of $\phi$ are given by

$$x' = x(1 − \frac{z}{1+z^2})\qquad ,\qquad y' = y(1 − \frac{z}{1+z^2}).$$

*My attempt:* Projecting point $p(x , y , z)$ onto plane $z=0$, one gets $p'(x , y , 0)$. If $\phi(p) = (x' , y' , 0)$, then by using the Thales theorem one gets:
$$\frac{x'}{x} = \frac{y'}{y} = \frac{\sqrt{x'^2 + y'^2}}{x^2 + y^2}.$$
Since $p$ is on hyperboloid, we have $x^2 + y^2 = 1+ z^2$. Then 
$$x' = x \frac{\sqrt{x'^2 + y'^2}}{\sqrt{1 + z^2}} \qquad , \qquad y' = y \frac{\sqrt{x'^2 + y'^2}}{\sqrt{1 + z^2}}.$$
but I don't know how prove that $\sqrt{x'^2 + y'^2} = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - z$.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\textbf{p} = (X,Y,Z)$ be fixed. (We use capital letters for the coordinates of $p$ to differentiate from the coordinate functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$.)  We consider the plane through the origin spanned by the $z$-axis and the vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}(X,Y,0)$.  If we slice the hyperboloid by this plane, we get a hyperbola whose asymptotes have direction vectors 
$\textbf{v} = (X,Y, \sqrt{X^2+Y^2})$ and $\textbf{w} = (X,Y, -\sqrt{X^2+Y^2})$.

According to the description of $\varphi$, to get from $\textbf{p}$ to $\varphi(\textbf{p})$, we should travel along the line through $\textbf{p}$ with direction vector $\textbf{v}$ until we reach the $z = 0$ plane.  This line can be parameterized by
$$
\textbf{g}(t) = (X,Y,Z) + t\left(X,Y, \sqrt{X^2+Y^2} \right).
$$
One can compute that this line intersects the $z=0$ plane when we take 
$$
t_0 = - \frac{Z}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}.
$$
That is, $X’$ and $Y’$ are the first and second coordinates of $\textbf{g}(t_0)$, which means that
$$
X’ = X \left( 1 - \frac{Z}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}} \right) = X \left( 1 - \frac{Z}{\sqrt{Z^2+1}}\right)
$$ 
and 
$$
Y’ = Y \left( 1 - \frac{Z}{\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}}\right) = Y \left( 1 - \frac{Z}{\sqrt{Z^2+1}}\right),
$$
as claimed in your book.

Comment: this is a very nice answer. Thanks!